# Why can't I use this 'void' type in a range based for loop?

Tags: c++, range-based-loop

```
for(auto i: {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}){
    /* loop body */
}
```

I know I have other ways to get my work done. But I was just wondering why we cannot use such type of list in this loop.

It is giving me this error:

```
cannot use type 'void' as a range
```

Comment: what do you expect to be deduced for `auto` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818: I suppose OP would expect `std::initializer_list<int>` which seems natural.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes kind of natural. my close vote was not justified (at all)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{..}` has no types, so it is problematic for deduction needed for inner type, you might help by explicitly provide the type: (I used CTAD from C++17 here, before add `<int>`)

```
for (auto i: {std::initializer_list{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}){
    /* loop body */
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d79606f305852441)